# Invalid value for "lists" parameter: incorrect list element type: string required

Tags: terraform

When applying a configuration I get the following error:

```
Error: Invalid function argument
│ 
│   on modules/kubernetes_cluster/main.tf line 53, in resource "local_file" "kubespray_inventory":
│   53:     k8s_node_host              = replace(join("\", \"\n", local.all_nodes), "\", \"", "") 
│     ├────────────────
│     │ local.all_nodes is a list of object, known only after apply
│ 
│ Invalid value for "lists" parameter: incorrect list element type: string required.
```

This is what my locals block looks like:

```
locals {
   all_nodes_verbose_etcd = [for k, v in var.node_hosts:
                               format("%s ip=%s etcd_instance=%s", v.name, v.ipv4_address, v.etcd_instance)
                               if length(v.etcd_instance) > 0]

   all_nodes_verbose      = [for k, v in var.node_hosts:
                               format("%s ip=%s", v.name, v.ipv4_address)
                               if length(v.etcd_instance) == 0]

   master_nodes           = [for k, v in var.node_hosts:
                               v.name
                               if v.compute_node != true]

   etcd_nodes             = [for k, v in var.node_hosts:
                               v.name
                               if length(v.etcd_instance) > 0]

   all_nodes              = values(var.node_hosts)[*].name

   kubernetes_conf_file = format("%s/kubespray/inventory/%s/group_vars/k8s-cluster/k8s-cluster.yml", pathexpand("~"), var.kubespray_inventory)
   kubespray_inv_file   = format("%s/kubespray/inventory/%s/inventory.ini", pathexpand("~"), var.kubespray_inventory)
   context_artifact     = format("%s/kubespray/inventory/%s/artifacts/admin.conf", pathexpand("~"), var.kubespray_inventory)
}
```

kubespray_invenotory.tpl template:

```
[all]
${k8s_node_host_verbose_etcd}
${k8s_node_host_verbose}

[kube-master]
${k8s_master_host}

[etcd]
${k8s_etcd_host}

[kube-node]
${k8s_node_host}

[calico-rr]

[k8s-cluster:children]
kube-master
kube-node
calico-rr
```

This is the local_file resource where the error is thrown:

```
resource "local_file" "kubespray_inventory" {
  content = templatefile("${path.module}/templates/var.kubespray_inventory.tpl", {
    k8s_node_host_verbose_etcd = replace(join("\", \"\n", local.all_nodes_verbose_etcd), "\", \"", "")
    k8s_node_host_verbose      = replace(join("\", \"\n", local.all_nodes_verbose), "\", \"", "")
    k8s_master_host            = replace(join("\", \"\n", local.master_nodes), "\", \"", "")
    k8s_etcd_host              = replace(join("\", \"\n", local.etcd_nodes), "\", \"", "")
    k8s_node_host              = replace(join("\", \"\n", local.all_nodes), "\", \"", "")
  })
  filename = local.kubespray_inv_file

  depends_on = [
    null_resource.kubespray
  ]
}
```

This is the definition for node_hosts in my variables.tf file:

```
variable "node_hosts" {
  type = map(map(object({
      name          = string
      compute_node  = bool
      etcd_instance = string
      ipv4_address  = string
    })))
}
```

and this is what node_hosts looks like in my tfvars file:

```
node_hosts = {
  default = {
    z-ca-arc-control1 = {
      name          = "z-ca-arc-control1"
      compute_node  = false
      etcd_instance = "etcd1"
      ipv4_address  = "10.123.456.01"
    },
    z-ca-arc-control2 =  {
      name          = "z-ca-arc-control2"
      compute_node  = false
      etcd_instance = "etcd2"
      ipv4_address  = "10.123.456.02"
    },
    z-ca-arc-compute1 = {
      name          = "z-ca-arc-compute1"
      compute_node  = true
      etcd_instance = "etcd3"
      ipv4_address  = "10.123.456.03"
    },
    z-ca-arc-compute2 = {
      name          = "z-ca-arc-compute2"
      compute_node   = true
      etcd_instance = ""
      ipv4_address  = "10.123.456.04"
    },
    z-ca-arc-compute3 = {
      name          = "z-ca-arc-compute3"
      compute_node  = true
      etcd_instance = ""
      ipv4_address  = "10.123.456.05"
    }
  }
}
```

I've attempted to solve this by changing the name element at the bottom most level of the nested map to a list, but this just results in a different error. Curiously, when I do away with the definition of node_hosts in the variables file and go with:

```
variable node_hosts = {
  default = {
    z-ca-arc-control1 = {
      name          = "z-ca-arc-control1"
      compute_node  = false
      etcd_instance = "etcd1"
      ipv4_address  = "10.123.456.01"
    },
    z-ca-arc-control2 =  {
      name          = "z-ca-arc-control2"
      compute_node  = false
      etcd_instance = "etcd2"
      ipv4_address  = "10.123.456.02"
    },
    z-ca-arc-compute1 = {
      name          = "z-ca-arc-compute1"
      compute_node  = true
      etcd_instance = "etcd3"
      ipv4_address  = "10.123.456.03"
    },
    z-ca-arc-compute2 = {
      name          = "z-ca-arc-compute2"
      compute_node   = true
      etcd_instance = ""
      ipv4_address  = "10.123.456.04"
    },
    z-ca-arc-compute3 = {
      name          = "z-ca-arc-compute3"
      compute_node  = true
      etcd_instance = ""
      ipv4_address  = "10.123.456.05"
    }
  }
}
```

the code works, I wonder if the use of default = in my tfvars file is incorrect.

Comment: Your question is very confusing. Your error is from `resource "local_file" "kubespray_inventory"` which is not shown. The `node_hosts looks like in my tfvars file` is incorrect, you can't have `default` value there. `variable node_hosts = {` is also incorrect TF syntax. Can you please edit your question to clarify what your codebase actually is?

Comment: Sorry about that, I've added the local_file resource to the question

Comment: What is `var.kubespray_inventory.tpl`?

Comment: I've added this to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything seems to be fine, except that your `default` and variable `node_hosts` do not match. In my view, if you make them as follows, it will work:

```
variable "node_hosts" {
  type = map(object({
      name          = string
      compute_node  = bool
      etcd_instance = string
      ipv4_address  = string
    }))
}
```

In **tfvars** it would be:

```
node_hosts =  {
    z-ca-arc-control1 = {
      name          = "z-ca-arc-control1"
      compute_node  = false
      etcd_instance = "etcd1"
      ipv4_address  = "10.123.456.01"
    },
    z-ca-arc-control2 =  {
      name          = "z-ca-arc-control2"
      compute_node  = false
      etcd_instance = "etcd2"
      ipv4_address  = "10.123.456.02"
    },
    z-ca-arc-compute1 = {
      name          = "z-ca-arc-compute1"
      compute_node  = true
      etcd_instance = "etcd3"
      ipv4_address  = "10.123.456.03"
    },
    z-ca-arc-compute2 = {
      name          = "z-ca-arc-compute2"
      compute_node   = true
      etcd_instance = ""
      ipv4_address  = "10.123.456.04"
    },
    z-ca-arc-compute3 = {
      name          = "z-ca-arc-compute3"
      compute_node  = true
      etcd_instance = ""
      ipv4_address  = "10.123.456.05"
    }
  }
```

Comment: I specify the actual values for node_hosts in a tfvars file, how do I specify a variable clause which specifies the structure of node_hosts in the tfvar file ?

Comment: Many thanks, this is not the first time you have helped me out, and it is very much appreciated, enjoy the rest of your day.